# Granting permissions to PostgreSQL user

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to grant permissions to one of my Postgres users.
I am running CentOS with PostgreSQL, Ruby On Rails 3, ruby 1.9.3

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON loadmax TO loadmax;
ERROR:  relation "loadmax" does not exist


 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd | userepl |  passwd  |
 valuntil | useconfig
----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+
----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t         | t       | ******** |
          |
 loadmax  |    16385 | t           | t        | t         | f       | ******** |


postgres=# CREATE DATABASE loadmax;
ERROR:  database "loadmax" already exists
```

I am trying to migrate my database. Apparently, my user doesn't have rights to create tables.

```
$ cap deploy:migrate
  * ←[32m2014-03-28 13:48:39 executing `deploy:migrate'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "ls -x /home/deployer/loadmax/releases"←[0m
    servers: ["108.235.52.160"]
Password:
    [108.235.52.160] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 625ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140328183628 && bundle
exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"←[0m
    servers: ["108.235.52.160"]
    [108.235.52.160] executing command
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does
not exist
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] LINE 1: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table
_name='schema_mi...
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] ^
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] : SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name=
'schema_migrations'
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160]
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
 ** [out :: 108.235.52.160] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 19619ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/loadmax/releases/20140328183628 && bundle exec
 rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 108.235.52.160
```

i have set the permissions as craig ringer suggested... but still i have the same issue and can not rake the database

```
[root@digihaul3-pc current]# rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_mi...
                      ^
: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_migrations'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Going by the update to the question, I'd say your original diagnosis was wrong. The problem is not to do with permissions at all. Instead, it seems more likely that the PostGIS extension is not installed but your code assumes it'll be installed, or that an earlier step failed but reported success so the migration process is broken. (I've removed my answer).